# Displaying user data from Firebase DB

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I am trying to match two collections within firebase user their unique user id and display the data from each collection if they exists within that collection. all together there are 6 different collections that i need to check if those users exist and if they do they i will need to display all of their information. 
Here are some printscreens of my database:
[image: these are the weight categories for fighters minus light heavyweight]

[image: this is the user collection where their initial details are located]
I have changed it so all their details are now located in the same collection

so i have tried a few things to try and do this. the first thing was that instead of passing the data into different collections i tried to have it all in once collection and then get the information from there but i am unable to figure out how to display those details for each user. I think i need to pass it into an array but not entirely sure on how to do it and unable to find anything on the internet to try and figure this out. I am able to `console.log` all the user details and i am able to successfully get those details from firebase matching that users UID but not entirely sure on how to display that data.

Here is my code:
This is how i am getting that data from firebase, i just need to know how to display all users within that collection with their matching data.

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(data=>{
      var ref = firebase.database().ref().child(`users/${data.uid}`);
      if(ref != null){
        ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {

          console.log(snapshot.val());
        }, function (errorObject) {
          console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
        });

      }
      else(err)=>{
        console.log(err);
      }


    }
    )
```

this is some of my HTML

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let key of filteredusers">
      <ion-item >
        <ion-avatar item-left>
          <img src="{{key.photoURL}}">
        </ion-avatar>
        <h2>{{key.displayName}}</h2> 
        <p>s</p> 
      </ion-item>
```

I am able to get their display name and their profile picture but as i was following a tutorial in the beginning so this is why i can get the users display name and photo URL but am i am unsure on how to get the rest of the data. 
I am relatively new to Ionic so any help would be appreciated.

I have tried adding something like this but this is still not working.

```
<h3>{{key.weight}}</
<h3>{{key.age}}</h3>
```

the way that I am getting the data from firebase is like this.

```
firedata = firebase.database().ref('/users');


  getallusers() {
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.firedata.orderByChild('uid').once('value', (snapshot) => {
        let userdata = snapshot.val();
        let temparr = [];
        for (var key in userdata) {
          temparr.push(userdata[key]);
        }
        resolve(temparr);
      }).catch((err) => {
        reject(err);
      })
    })
    return promise;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured it out how to display the weight for the user and other details.
I just passed the details in the same collection within firebase instead of having it in different collections. Then I just called that data in the HTML.

```
 <ion-card-content> 
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let key of filteredusers">
      <ion-item >
        <ion-avatar item-left>
          <img src="{{key.photoURL}}">
        </ion-avatar>
        <h2>{{key.displayName}}</h2> 
          <h3>{{key.weight}}</h3>
      </ion-item>
```

so i added {{key.weight}} as now they are in the same collection i can just call that data within the HTML.